# Expanding JSON array to text values with NULL

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm having issues to generate a query to display a JSON array to a set of text values when having NULL values. Suppose I have the following table:

```
Name | Meta
Art0 | {"category":["sport"]}
Art1 | [NULL]
Art2 | {"category":["sport", "health"]}
```

If I do something like:

```
SELECT name, jsonb_array_elements_text(meta->'category') tag FROM table
```

I'm getting the following results:

```
Name | Tag
Art0 | sport
Art2 | sport
Art2 | health
```

The problem is that Art1 is being removed. How can I execute a query that also includes a row for Art1 and an empty string or NULL value on the Tag column?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And without `join`/`union`:

```
SELECT
  name,
  jsonb_array_elements_text(coalesce(meta->'category', '[null]')) tag
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `left join`:

```
select name, tag 
from my_table
left join jsonb_array_elements_text(meta->'category') as tag on true

 name |  tag   
------+--------
 Art0 | sport
 Art1 | 
 Art2 | sport
 Art2 | health
(4 rows)
```

This is a lateral join, i.e. the function is executed once for each row from the table. Usually such a join is written down as `cross join` but we want to get results also when the function returns nothing. To accomplish this we can use `left join`, which needs a join condition, so we are using `true` as always fulfilled condition.

Comment: Is `..on true` psql specific or standard SQL? Can you explain how/why it works?

Comment: This solution is nice because it works if categories is missing or if it's an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with `LEFT JOIN` just like when dealing with tables:

```
SELECT name, tag FROM table
LEFT OUTER JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(meta->'category') tag ON TRUE
```

Would result in:

```
name    tag
Art0    sport
Art1    (null)
Art2    sport
Art2    health
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `union`

```
SELECT name, jsonb_array_elements_text(meta->'category') tag FROM table UNION 
SELECT id, attrs::text tag FROM table where meta is null;
```

Result:

```
name    tag
Art0    sport
Art2    sport
Art2    health
Art1
```